# Проблема с выводом переменной c#

Tags: c#

Не понимаю почему мой код неправильно выводит введенную пользователем int-переменную.

Сам код:

```
Console.Write("Введите число: ");

int z = Console.Read();

Console.WriteLine(z);
```

**Пример ввода и вывода:**

> Ввод: 1
>
> Вывод: 49

Comment: вы читаете не число, а код символа `1`. Попробуйте `int z = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`

Comment: @tym32167 работает, но если мне нужно не одно число, а скажем, 3. Можно ли как-то без массивов обойтись? Или придется все числа в массив записывать, а потом выгружать их?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фишка в том, что Console.Read() возвращает код символа в формате ASCII, а не сам символ. Вы ввели "1", код которого равен 49 в таблице ASCII в десятичной системе [ссылка](https://www.asciitable.com/).

Вы же можете вместо Console.Read() использовать Console.ReadLine(), который вернет введенную строку полностью, а затем преобразовать эту строку в целое число с помощью метода Int32.Parse(), и тогда вы увидите введённое число, а не его код:

```
Console.Write("Введите число: ");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
int z = Int32.Parse(input);
Console.WriteLine(z);
```